# How would I get desired columns data from Sequelize models using findone

Tags: sequelize.js

I would like to `retrieve` two columns from a table using `sequelize`  library. The below return all columns inside the table.

```
const userEmail = req.body.email;
const data = await LinkTokenModel.findAll({ where: { email: userEmail } });
```

Following is my expected select query, `SELECT token, expiredAt FROM <db_name>.<table_name> where email="someEmail@test.com";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify attributes/columns in an array of strings. So you could do something like:

```
LinkTokenModel.findAll({attributes: ['token','expiredAt'], where:{...}})
```

You can read more about querying and see more examples in the [Sequelize docs here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#specifying-attributes-for-select-queries)

Comment: Will try that today evening and reply with the outcome.

Comment: Appreciate your help, the following works for me ``const data = await LinkTokenModel.findAll({ attributes: ['token','expiredAt']}, { where: { email: userEmail }} );``
There is a close parenthisis at the end of attributes `{ attributes: ['token','expiredAt']}` without that it was not working. Could you please update the answer

Comment: I'm hesitant to update the answer with code you've provided. This would be inconsistent with both the current documentation and with my own experience. Your code is passing two parameters to findAll where the documented [method signature](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll) requires one.

Comment: No problem at all, appreciate your reply